# cannot update the ref..Not a directory

Tags: git, git-pull

I am on `master` branch and trying to pull.
I get following error:

```
error: cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/occupancy': unable to append to '.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/occupancy': Not a directory
From github.com:oyorooms/oyo-retention-service
 ! [new branch]        hotfix/occupancy -> origin/hotfix/occupancy  (unable to update local ref)
```

I have tried following commands:

```
git gc --prune=now
git remote prune origin
git pull
```

But none worked for me. Please help.

NOTE: git pull origin master is working, But i need to correct this error.

Comment: You have to specify a remote and branch when doing a pull. The statement should look like: `git pull origin master` in your case

Comment: Yes, this is working, But how to solve error from git pull.

Comment: You might want to try deleting `.git/refs/remote/origin` after executing `git gc --prune=now` and `git remote prune origin` and then do a `git pull`

Comment: rm: .git/refs/remote/origin: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a branch named `hotfix`?

Comment: @phd, and if so, how is it related?

Comment: @0andriy You cannot have branches `hotfix` and `hotfix/occupancy` at the same time.

Comment: @phd, A-ha, makes sense! Git special treatment of `/`... Or otherwise, no treatment at all.